# Aerospike -- Read and Write Records with filters and without a key

Tags: aerospike

I'm working on a project which uses Aerospike and nodejs. Previous I have worked on Nodejs and Mongodb(mongoose to be more specific).
The use case that I'm struck is simple. Say the records in a set has bins called say `"isReady"` and `"time"` . Based on a particular action by the user I want to read all the records with "isReady" false and based on some condition on `"time"` set `"isReady"` to true. 
This is a very simple if in mongoose or if we know the key of each record.
Currently I'm storing the primary key as part of the record as `"reckey"`. Please let know how to do it without storing the primary key .

Code :

```
var client = getAeroSpikeClient();
var queryArgs = {
  filters: [
    filter.equal('isReady', false)
  ]
};

var query = client.query('ns', 'set', queryArgs)
var stream = query.execute();
var data = []
stream.on('data', function(record){
    if (record)
        data.push(record)
}):
stream.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Error')
});
stream.on('end', function() {
    $(data).each(function(i, it) {
        if (it.time > 10)
            it.isReady = true
        client.put(it.reckey, it, function(err) {
            if (err.code != aerospike.status.AEROSPIKE_OK)
               console.log('Success')
        })
    })
)}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the queries you want to make?

Comment: How many records will be changed? You can, in theory, use a stream UDF that is called upon all records (filtered by a secondary index, e.g. by userID).

Comment: Yea need to check if we can use streamUDF.  That would put the processing load to the cluster rather than to application. Let me check it and get back

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for applying a Record UDF to each record matched by your query. That way the processing is done entirely server side and you don't need to fetch all records to the client and write them back.

You can find more background information on Record UDFs in the [technical documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/record_udf.html). The Node.js client's Query API is documented in the client's [API documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Query.html).

In your particular use case you would use a [background query](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Query.html#background):

```
var query = client.query(namespace, set)
query.where(Aeropspike.filter.equal('isReady', 0))
query.background('myUdfModule', 'updateIsReady', [10], (err, job) => {
  if (err) throw err
  job.waitUntilDone((err) => {
    console.info('All done!')
  })
})
```

The `updateIsReady` Lua function would look something like this:

```
function updateIsReady(rec, timeLimit)
  if (rec['time'] > timeLimit) then
    rec['isReady'] = 1
    aerospike:update(rec)
  end
end
```

You would first need to register the UDF module with the cluster using the client's [`udfRegister`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Client.html#udfRegister) method. You will also need to create an integer index on `isReady` using [`createIndex`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Client.html#createIndex). (Note that Aerospike does not support boolean bin values at the moment. It's best to represent `isReady` using integer values 0 and 1.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions (where clause) only on indexes. By default only PK is indexed. If you want to query based on `isReady` and `time`, you can create secondary index on that and it will work. e.g.

```
select * from namespace.set where isReady = false
```

This query is not possible if isReady is not secondary index.